# what is the replacement of " for line in sys.stdin: " in C?

Tags: python, c

I am asked to convert a python program to a C program.The Python program includes the loop statement which i am unable to convert.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    <Some Code>
```

I am looking for its substitution in C.I thought the following code might work but I doubt it.

```
char A[100]
while(1)
A=gets();
```

Try to be elaborate.

Comment: are you reading a file, or stream?

Comment: I think you want `while (fgets(A, sizeof(A), stdin) != NULL) { <Some Code> }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second Joachim's response:

```
char A[100]; /* Your code misses the semicolon here. */

while(fgets(A, sizeof A, stdin) != NULL)
{
  /* process A here */
}
```

do note that this is limited to a line length of 100 characters, the Python code is not limited in that way.

If you have it, use [`getline()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) instead, it has no length limit.

Answer (score 0):

there has much choices for you to chose:

```
int fgetc(FILE *stream)
char *fgets(char *s,int n,FILE *stream)
int getc(FILE *stream)
size_t fread(void *ptr,size_t size,size_t nobj,FILE *stream)
```

you can't use the code you just give:

```
1.code from python means get from stdin
2.with no limits of 100 characters.
```